# について Usage and Honorifics Subject

Tags: translation, expressions, parsing, homonyms

I have the following sentence to translate.

```
父母や教師達は、もっとよく子どもの教育について、考えていただきたいものだ。
```

So far I have the following.

```
Parents and teachers "do something" better with children's education and they want the 
children to think.
```

I am having trouble understanding which `つく` verb is being used.

And I also am not sure who has the desire in the sentence. I think it's the parents and teachers as they have the subject marker. But then the `いただきたい` is weird because of the honorifics. Did the subject of the sentence change?

Comment: Did you realize that について is a fixed expression?

Comment: Nope, I didn't. I assumed it was the て form of a verb acting upon 教育 with the に

Answer (score 3):

について is a fixed expression meaning "regarding, concerning, ..." (here "about" also works) and [derives from 就く or 付く](http://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%AB%E5%B0%B1%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6?dic=daijisen&oid=14047000), although it is usually written in かな.

Comment: Could you address how the honorifics comes into play as well?

Answer (score 3):

もらいたい・いただきたい's usage is waving these days. It originally takes dative に for the marker of the agent, but people have started to use nominative as well, as a result, the situation is being more or less confusing. 
i.e. 父母や教師達には…考えていただきたいものだ → 父母や教師達は…考えていただきたいものだ

Answer (score 1):

From a grammatical point of view I think it could be rephrased as:

> (私は、)父母や教師達*に*は、もっとよく子どもの教育について、考えていただきたい{ものだ/と思う}。

-私は = I = the subject for 考えていただきたい
-父母や教師たちに = for parents and teachers = the subject for 考える
-もっとよく = more seriously <--- modifies 考える.
-子どもの教育について = about children's education <--- modifies 考える.
-考えていただきたい* = the humble form of 考えてもらいたい = (I) want (someone) to think. >> I want parents and teachers to think (more seriously about...). 
-ものだ >> [goo辞書#5-㋑](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/219726/m0u/) emphasis

*いただく is the humble form ([謙譲語]{けんじょうご}) of もらう.

Answer (score 1):

(This is supplementary to Chocolate's answer.)

If you put everything together then we get:

> I would like parents and teachers to think much more about their childrens' education.

Note that:

- いただきたい makes the sentence from the viewpoint of the  writer.
- Parents and teachers are the topic (marked by は): that is to say, the focus of the speaker/writers utterance.
- ものだ indicates the sincerity or importance the writer places on the statement.

Comment: Plus a typo in いただいた... Also, I think this is coursework/homework, so personally I prefer to leave explicit answers to the asker.

Comment: @Earthliŋ : 1) what is missing 2) Not sure I understand your preference, unless it is  principle about plagiarism.  I think the translation makes all the difference to the pupil's understanding. The OP is 27 so I assume she knows how to behave responsibly.

Comment: 1) snailboat corrected your typos. 2) If she's been given a homework problem, then I just think that doing it 100% for her will be interfering with her course.